# How and where to buy money order for VFS Canada visa

Tags: canada, money, vfs-global

I will keep having help, indeed, I applied for a visa and IRCC asked me to submit my passport to VFS.

On the VFS GLOBAL website they say to send an amount of 22.80 by money order. I did this through western union, and refunded it all through an expensive courier paid obligated to them.

I receive a return, informing me that I have not paid the fees, I forward the scanners by email, and in return, they tell me that they do not take this kind of payment.

I go to their site to chat with customer service, because the switchboard is unreachable, and on the chat, I'm asked to pay a money order, so I don't really know what to do.

Thank you for those who have already had this experience where to do the mandate so as not to have a problem.

Comment: What country are you applying from?

Comment: Thank for your reply, I'm applying from USA.

Comment: For a money order [I'll guess USPS](https://www.usps.com/shop/money-orders.htm). It isn't clear to me that a money order is required, however, as everywhere I look on the VFS Global web site lists a cashier's check as an alternative. The latter can be bought from banks.

Comment: @Dennis Yeah you're right, when I see a mandat, I can express many things like western union, money gram and others elses. On their website, they suggest a cashier's check but I don't have a bank account in USA, In France where I come, to obtain a cashier's check you need a own account on the bank. Finally, I recontact their customer service and they told me that they accept Eleven Moner Order, USPS. But ironically the eleven moner order is Western Union, I did already western union, they refused. I send finally on usps order.